# mysql - query does not always display result when true

Tags: mysql

I am running the following query in mysql and depending on what value has been added will depend if the system displays a row when I run the query. Each row as a value and this should not be a problem and all values that her in the database should display a row but this is not the case, here is my query.

If I enter golf the correct row will show but not for football.

```
CREATE TABLE `sports` (
  `sport_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Tag` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `sports` (`sport_ID`, `Name`, `Tag`) VALUES
(1, 'Football', 'Rugby'),
(2, 'Rugby', 'Basketball'),
(3, 'Basketball', 'Golf'),
(4, 'Golf', 'Football')


SELECT *
FROM sports b 
join sports a
on a.Tag = b.Name
where b.sport_ID > a.sport_ID and a.Tag = 'Football'
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The code needs to be in the question not at the end of a (broken) link.

Comment: the link shouldn't be broken

Comment: No query is shown

Comment: I known I'm trying to fix it

Comment: @Beck please accept the answer if it worked to close this question properly.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `>` by `<>`:

```
SELECT *
FROM sports b 
left join sports a
on a.Tag = b.Name
where b.sport_ID <> a.sport_ID and a.Tag = 'golf'
LIMIT 1
```

It returns a row now both for `golf` and `football`.

**BUT**

I suspect that your problem might be more complex than that, perhaps the sample is too small.

Comment: One more thing to note here is using `LIMIT` without ordering is pretty much useless.

Comment: yeah that didn't seem to fix the problem

Comment: @Beck what do you mean? It does return one row, doesn't it?

Comment: this is what it returns "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0004 seconds.)"

Comment: @Beck here is a [working demo](http://rextester.com/SYK60403), what is wrong with that?

Comment: yes it might work for golf but if I can the word to basketball it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Sure it does! This is what it returns: `1 3 Basketball Golf 2 Rugby Basketball`.

Comment: Did you mistype something?

Comment: no wait I checked it again and it is still only working with certain words i.e it works with golf but to rugby

Comment: and as you said that is what it should return that but it doesn't always do that

Comment: Results for rugby: `2 Rugby Basketball 1 Football Rugby`. I think your are trolling.

Comment: nope honestly it doesn't do that when I run it in mysql

Comment: If you have the exact same data it will run, since it runs in the demo! If you have different data you might just have a **different problem**.

Comment: oops was copying old code and had some of my information the wrong way round, it works fine now, thank you :-)

Comment: I see; so if your problem is solved, please accept the answer as well.